# Convert from Uri to file path in web application context

Tags: java, spring, google-drive-api, tomcat7

I need to load a keys file to create a `GoogleCredential` instance on my server. 
I got the URL to the resource which is in my `WEB-INF/resources` directory using

```
url = servletContext.getResource(RESOURCES_FOLDER + "/" + filePath);
```

which returns:

```
"jndi:/localhost/<MY_APP>/WEB-INF/resources/<MY_FILE>"
```

The problem is that `GoogleCredential.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File` requires a File object as a parameter.

When creating a `File` using

```
f = new File(url.getFile());
```

f is being created but with the wrong path.

```
f.getAbsolutePath() = D:\localhost\<MY_APP>\WEB-INF\resources\secrets.p12
```

How to convert URL to File in a web server context? Or is there is an easier way to create a 
`GoogleCredential` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - use `this.getClass()` instead of the servletContext:

```
new java.io.File(this.getClass().getResource(RESOURCES_FOLDER + "/" + filePath).toURI());
```

UPDATE:

Actually, I'd take a look at your URL that you're using to get the resource too. Any time you are using `.getResource`, the default url is to point at the `/src/main/resources` directory. The url that you pass into the `.getResources` method should be any folder structure from that point.

For example if my folder structure is:

```
   -src
      -main
        -resources
           -googlecredentials.properties
```

All you need to pass in is: `this.getClass().getResource("googlecredentials.properties");`

If my folder structure is:

```
   -src
      -main
        -resources
           -google
              -googlecredentials.properties
```

I need to pass in: `this.getClass().getResource("google/googlecredentials.properties");`

You never want to prefix the resource url with a `/`. That would mean that you're looking from your hard drive's root (absolute path). You want a relative path to the resources.

Comment: when not prefixing with "/" the path is inside the package meaning: 
url = this.getClass().getResource("");
returns $<TOMCAT_PATH>/webapps/<MY_WEBAPP>/WEB-INF/classes/com/core/repository/fixture/

url = this.getClass().getResource("/");
returns $<TOMCAT_PATH>/webapps/devstage-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/

The later makes more sense. Thanks